# about the Linux Shell 'While' command

Tags: linux, shell

code:

```
path=$PATH:
while [ -n $path ]
do 
ls -ld ${path%%:*}
path=${path#*:}
done
```

I want to get the each part of path .When run the script ,it can not get out of the while process 。Please tell me why . Is some problem in 'while [ -n $path ]' ？

Comment: echo $PATH | tr : '\012' | while read d; do ls -ld ${d:-.}; done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final cut never results in an empty string. If you have a:b:c, you'll strip off the a and then the b, but never the c. I.e., this:

```
${path#*:}
```

Will always result in a non-empty string for the last piece of the path. Since the -n check looks for an empty string, your loop runs forever.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forget to add ':' after the code 'path=$PATH'

Comment: Huh odd, now I see what you mean. Well, try `! -z $path` instead of `-n $path`. That seems to work fine.

Comment: Ah now I got it. You need to put quotes around the variable: `-n "$path"` Without the quotes, it ends up being equivalent to `while [ -n ]` when $path is empty.

Comment: It's right。Thanks for your help 。I want to know when I forgot to add quotes ，why the loop still output the "." However You said the $path is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If `$path` doesn't have a colon in it, `${path#*:}` will return `$path`. So you have an infinite loop.

```
p="foo"
$ echo ${p#*:}
foo
$ p="foo:bar"
$ echo ${p#*:}
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some bugs in your code. This should do the trick:

```
path=$PATH
while [[ $path != '' ]]; do
    # you can replace echo to whatever you need, like ls -ld
    echo ${path%%:*}
    if echo $path | grep ':' >/dev/null; then 
        path=${path#*:}
    else path=''
    fi
done
```

Your `path`, after is initialized, will always check `True` for `[ -n path ]` test. This is the main reason for which you never get out of the `while` loop.